# Why is layout not appearing in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I cannot figure out why nothing is appearing with my code. Everything is set using a linearlayout, which I am accustomed to yet nothing takes effect when the code is compiled and run. (No errors in the log either) I'm sure I'm just looking over something simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemprofilelayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toplayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itempicture"
                android:contentDescription=" "
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:src="@drawable/budlight_sample" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/iteminformation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/middlelayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/socialoptions"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemratings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemreviews"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Activity:

```
package My.Taste.App;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ItemListActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the actual code you use to show this layout file?

Comment: I posted it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I assume itemlist is the name of your shown xml file? Plus does your xml file compile? Can you view it in eclipse design view.

Comment: `1.` Are you running it on a GoogleAPi device? `2.` Shouldn't you extend MapActivity? `3.` Can't recall but I think you should mention the whole qualified name of MapView in xml.

Comment: MapView was one error, so I went ahead and removed it for now, changing it to a temporary TextView. Now a white bar appears at the bottom of the screen and that is it.

Comment: " Now a white bar appears at the bottom of the screen and that is it." See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing the top half of the code with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemprofilestartup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp" >
```

Answer (score 4):

I have never used a MapView. But it is not a standard Android View, try using the full name:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    ... />
```

But if this isn't the problem you also have many of your `layout_width` attributes set to `0dp`. When I changed the width of your ImageView to `wrap_content` it displayed fine. Also you won't see any of your TextView's because you haven't passed them any text yet.

Comment: You were right about the MapView being part of the problem along with changing the wrap_content to make the views visible, but when changing the 0dp the weights no longer work which means the layout doesn't set properly.

Comment: So changing the widths to `wrap_content` affects your `layout_weights`?

Comment: It makes them no longer effective. In a previous layout of mine when I change the layout_widhth or layout_height from 0dp to wrap_content it causes the layout to completely alter. And like that, when I change the width attribute the views size change despite the weights. Example: the id/itemprofile is suddenly taking up a majority of the screen instead of the 30% allotted to it through weights.